# results array between two values - javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers, between

i was wondering if there is a way to get an array with minimum and maximum values get by another array, or something like this:

```
var numbers = ['10','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50'];  

var getnumbers = function(min,max){
 //return a result that is push to another array, in this case "results"
};
getnumbers(10,30);
console.log(results);
```

the output should give me something like 10 - 15 - 20 - 25 - 30

Comment: You can define a global array like numbers and push in it, or you can create a temp array in getnumbers and return it.

Comment: ok, get it, but i'm not sure how to get the numbers array value like the output.

Comment: I believe @Nina, answer is perfect, but an alternative could be looping over numbers array and pushing it into an array and return it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A slightly different approach, with a customized callback function for filtering.

```js
function filterNumbers(min, max) {
    return function (a) { return a >= min && a <= max; };
}

var numbers = ['10', '15', '20', '25', '30', '35', '40', '45', '50'],
    result = numbers.filter(filterNumbers(10, 30));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like: `numbers.filter(function (value) { return value >= 10 && value <= 30 });`

And if you really want the output to be `N1 - N2 - N3 ... - NN`, just do `numbers.filter(function (value) { return value >= 10 && value <= 30 }).join(' - ');`

Comment: you'd need to cast v to a number

Comment: It will be done automatically; the array is made up of strings. Weird JavaScript things, you know...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var numbers = ['10','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50'];  
var output = "";
var getnumbers = function(min,max){
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
    if(numbers[i] >= min && numbers[i] <= max){
      output += numbers[i] + "-";
    }
  }
};
getnumbers(10,30);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: also yours is very valid

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has inbuilt functions to solve this issue.

```
let numbers = ['10','15','20','25','30','35','40','45','50'];
// Get all elements between '10' and '30'
let result = numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf('10'),numbers.indexOf('30') + 1);
console.log(result);
// If you want the answer to literally be '10-15-20-25-30'
let resultString = "";
for(const i in result){
    resultString.concat(`${result[i]}-`)
}
console.log(resultString);
```